# Azure time and Web API

Tags: c#, datetime, azure, asp.net-web-api

When an iPhone app calls my web API, if it passes a DateTime (e.g., it's iPhone local time), when it reaches Web API, is it automatically converted to UTC time?

My Web API:

```
public class MyDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

 }


public IHttpActionResult PostNews(MyDTO currentDTO)
{
     Trace.WriteLine("create time is {0}. Kind is {1}", currentDTO.TimeStamp.ToLongTimeString(), currentDTO.TimeStamp.Kind);
}
```

I found the trace shows UTC time, and the Kind is UTC. I am really confused. I thought TimeStamp should be iPhone's local time, whatever it is.

Comment: I think it depends on how you serialise `NSDateTime` on the iPhone app. You should provide your HTTP request data here. Is it JSON or XML?

Comment: Not sure if this could be the issue but you passing in currentDTO but Trace.Writeline is called on newsDTO

Comment: @tia, it is JSON. So you are saying it is the problem at iPhone end instead of Web API end?

Comment: @ElvisLives, sorry that is a typo, should be currentDTO. I corrected it.

Comment: I think it is at iPhone end. You should check raw HTTP request and see the JSON directly. Is the time correct in UTC anyway?

Comment: @tia, yes, the time is correct in UTC

Comment: Well, I made some tested and got enough information, but please clarify what you really want it to be so I can answer correctly. One thing is that client should always send ISO 8601 date, either as UTC (Z) or along with local time zone indicator (+XX:XX).